# Rails find record start with non alphabetic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

in Ruby on Rails, how do I search records that start by non alphabetic character? Such as number or other char like #, bang (!), ? question mark, dot, comma, etc?

Comment: not yet. but I already deprecate feature that need this method on my app :(

Answer (score -1):

This is how I've done it. I'm not really sure about the performance, but it works fine in my case (about 50,000 indexed records).

```
#Rails 2
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["name < ?", "a"])

#Rails 3
Model.where("name < ?", "a")
```